# Why is the CSV file not found and unable to read when it's in the pwd?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, opencsv

I'm attempting to just open a CSV file and skip the first row to have only the values as the output. I tried using relative and absolute path and still get either error2 file not found or ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

```
import csv
with open('MOCK_DATA.csv','r') as f:
     mock_data_reader = csv.reader(f)

line_count = 1
for row in mock_data_reader:
    if line_count > 1: #skipping line 1 which is header row
        print(row)
     line_count += 1:
```

Comment: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Sorry, I realized I missed the indentation when uploading the code block when I posted the question initially. The indentation is correct and this code example is from the text of an online course I'm working through. Even though the syntax is correct, I'm still getting the previously mentioned error messages.

Comment: drunkenwhaler_136, welcome to StackOverflow! If you google `csv.reader` you will see its syntax examples, for example, https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reach the desired output of skipping the header row of the CSV file and printing the rest of the output. The textbook's example wasn't good but this makes much more sense and I'm still not sure why I needed to use the relative file path since the CSV file is in the PWD but it runs properly and skips the header row with the next(file_name) function.

```
import csv
with open('Lesson8_Modules_Packages_File_Operations/Mock_Data.csv', 'r') as f:
    mock_data_reader = csv.reader(f) 

    line_count = 1 
    next(mock_data_reader)
    for row in mock_data_reader: 
        if line_count > 0:
           print(row)
    line_count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce one of errors you mention running your code `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`. You need to indent a `for` loop. `MOCK_DATA.csv` is in the same folder.

```
import csv
with open('MOCK_DATA.csv', 'r') as f:
    mock_data_reader = csv.reader(f)

    line_count = 1
    for row in mock_data_reader:
        if line_count > 1: #skipping line 1 which is header row
            print(row)
        line_count += 1
```

Another variation:

```
import csv

line_count = 1
with open('MOCK_DATA.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        if line_count > 1: #skipping line 1 which is header row
            print row
        line_count += 1
```

Hope this will help you going.